# Get url of tab that called inject-script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

There is a problem.
I want to get url of tab that called inject-script content.js:

My *manifest.json*:

```
{  
  "background_page": "background.html",  
  "content_scripts": [ {  
    "all_frames": true,  
    "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],  
    "js": [ "content.js" ],  
    "run_at": "document_start"  
  } ],  
  "description": "Test...",  
  "name": "TestExt",  
  "permissions": [ "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],  
  "version": "0.1.0"  
}
```

My *content.js*:

```
document.addEventListener("beforeload", function(event) {
  console.log(document.location.href);
}, true);
```

Result for link *http://ya.ru*:

```
http://ya.ru/  
http://kiks.yandex.ru/system/fc06.html  
http://suggest.yandex.ru/jquery-1-4-2.crossframeajax.html
```

but i need to see this

```
http://ya.ru/  
http://ya.ru/  
http://ya.ru/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `window.top.document.location.href`.